# SVG image height auto doesn't work except in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using `image` tag in SVG to include website screen captures in mockups for my personal website. I've no problem when I'm visiting my website using Chrome, but using Firefox or Safari, I'm getting some issues.

It works like this: I define a SVG `mask`, the `image` use that mask to be in the "screen", and the image height is `auto` to be great displayed. Here is a snippet:

```html
<svg id="adf1338b-c638-44c9-9dd0-93df7f9f46b1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2148 1237.39">
  <defs>
    <filter id="e71a6e13-91a7-4c48-8db4-fd9f3d7680f9" x="-13.7" y="-110.5" width="128.3" height="140.2" name="filter-2">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetOuter1" dx="7.8" dy="7.8" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feGaussianBlur result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="81.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.06 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="952164c2-8d50-4072-8fbc-1daf64a9f996" data-name="Dégradé sans nom" x1="752.65" y1="994.07" x2="753.65" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -12, -1616691.37, 13126.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.04"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.04"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="cb01145d-084b-4051-a7b8-afc1075b337d" y="-94.6" width="100" height="107.1" name="filter-5">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetInner1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feComposite result="shadowInnerInner1" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha"></feComposite>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.02 0" in="shadowInnerInner1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 2" x1="744.83" y1="994.07" x2="743.59" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(80, 0, 0, -12, -57419, 13126.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
      id="d6b5fdf2-09db-48a0-a136-a0968d72d8fd"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 3"
      x1="743.59"
      y1="994.07"
      x2="744.59"
      y2="994.07"
      gradientTransform="matrix(80, 0, 0, -12, -59486.95, 13126.84)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 4" x1="752.65" y1="968.72" x2="753.65" y2="968.72" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#eaeaea" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="1b131c43-0dea-4a3e-b634-4bb33e458dcc" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 6" x1="753.15" y1="969.22" x2="753.15" y2="968.22" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="dc83dd5d-fe7a-4f3c-96dc-f9b3dd530f96" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 7" x1="753.15" y1="969.22" x2="753.15" y2="968.22" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.05"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.05"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="55d6f982-cfb0-43d5-b1ce-33840dcf898f" x="-0.1" y="-93.6" width="100.2" height="105.3" name="filter-13">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetInner1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feComposite result="shadowInnerInner1" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha"></feComposite>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.03 0" in="shadowInnerInner1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient
      id="0347f2e9-aa93-4a31-83dd-17fa4a18e4ef"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 8"
      x1="734.18"
      y1="984.18"
      x2="735.18"
      y2="984.18"
      gradientTransform="matrix(40, 0, 0, -16, -28499.14, 17037.76)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
      id="48a5c464-8edd-45c4-9ce5-a29ab784ca76"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 9"
      x1="735.17"
      y1="984.18"
      x2="734.17"
      y2="984.18"
      gradientTransform="matrix(40, 0, 0, -16, -28127.82, 17037.76)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <mask id="e5f414aa-2dc3-4e7e-beb9-c2665256ed3c" x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="1010" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <g transform="translate(0 -91)">
        <g id="5c9c027a-7ae5-4592-a798-6d4ba66f4659" data-name="mask-16">
          <rect id="b88cc6a8-61b0-4014-b1dc-ffc15d65cac1" data-name="path-15" x="264" y="170" width="1618" height="1010" fill="#fff"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g id="77173500-bfe4-412c-9f4c-6d18bf82908b" data-name="Artboard">
    <g id="98dd64aa-035e-4372-81a9-808b5df3da43" data-name="macbook">
      <g id="2528bcce-59cd-406f-8223-417b9dc2b419" data-name="bg">
        <g filter="url(#e71a6e13-91a7-4c48-8db4-fd9f3d7680f9)">
          <path
            id="a7e121fd-8fcd-4e60-8f74-4eb6bbc3617a"
            data-name="path-1"
            d="M296.42,91H1850.58c34,0,43.53,0,58.17,4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33,37.33c4.92,14.64,4.92,24.17,4.92,58.17V1223.58c0,34,0,43.53-4.92,58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33,37.33c-14.64,4.92-24.17,4.92-58.17,4.92H296.42c-34,0-43.53,0-58.17-4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33-37.33c-4.92-14.64-4.92-24.17-4.92-58.17V191.42c0-34,0-43.53,4.92-58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33-37.33C252.89,91,262.43,91,296.42,91Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"></path>
        </g>
        <path
          id="400dfe13-b733-4999-ba8f-7c75bc5675e2"
          data-name="path-1"
          d="M296.42,91H1850.58c34,0,43.53,0,58.17,4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33,37.33c4.92,14.64,4.92,24.17,4.92,58.17V1223.58c0,34,0,43.53-4.92,58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33,37.33c-14.64,4.92-24.17,4.92-58.17,4.92H296.42c-34,0-43.53,0-58.17-4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33-37.33c-4.92-14.64-4.92-24.17-4.92-58.17V191.42c0-34,0-43.53,4.92-58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33-37.33C252.89,91,262.43,91,296.42,91Z"
          transform="translate(0 -91)"
          fill="#fff"></path>
      </g>
      <path id="43c6a4ac-5af9-45b1-9c0a-e2b805fceea4" data-name="cam" d="M1070.5,133a6.5,6.5,0,1,1-6.5,6.5A6.5,6.5,0,0,1,1070.5,133Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#f2f2f2"></path>
      <g id="41b53099-7741-4f93-a5b1-bbc7d688aeca" data-name="Bottom">
        <g id="ed61ea5b-396c-4755-acc5-837900bb45dd" data-name="Rectangle-1">
          <polygon id="3f88510c-3940-406a-944f-ea423fac19a9" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192" fill="#fff"></polygon>
          <polygon id="12bddb6b-cf6b-4005-b437-57bd064462a3" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192" fill="url(#952164c2-8d50-4072-8fbc-1daf64a9f996)"></polygon>
          <g filter="url(#cb01145d-084b-4051-a7b8-afc1075b337d)">
            <polygon id="04c57957-d6c4-492a-af0d-9db3629d7056" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192"></polygon>
          </g>
        </g>
        <polygon id="9b3aec7b-87aa-41a2-8c6e-1a1021f35e95" data-name="gradient" points="2068 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 2068 1204 2068 1192" opacity="0.1" fill="url(#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c)" style="isolation: isolate"></polygon>
        <polygon id="2b964d54-6675-4afb-a411-aa203a5eaca1" data-name="gradient" points="0 1192 80 1192 80 1204 0 1204 0 1192" opacity="0.1" fill="url(#d6b5fdf2-09db-48a0-a136-a0968d72d8fd)" style="isolation: isolate"></polygon>
        <g id="0f4064a7-9754-48ad-8901-2956fe4271fa" data-name="bottom">
          <path id="6dfeff10-a16b-4114-9289-11ca4696184e" data-name="path-11" d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"></path>
          <path
            id="6ac336ae-89f9-44e0-8892-088e108b9b0c"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681)"></path>
          <path
            id="929a00e3-5dc1-434b-9ea2-499bfffeb4b7"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681)"></path>
          <path
            id="41d1f204-371f-4006-b6e3-3ca8e55170a4"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#1b131c43-0dea-4a3e-b634-4bb33e458dcc)"></path>
          <path
            id="3661128a-dd7f-4831-ad61-767d60316664"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#dc83dd5d-fe7a-4f3c-96dc-f9b3dd530f96)"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="be6e6ca0-ae80-4cfd-951c-f15752bfa1f4" data-name="Combined-shape-29">
          <path id="0381728f-4162-474f-a8a6-a34825b87739" data-name="path-12" d="M908,1283h371v11c0,4.22-40,5-40,5H908s-40-.78-40-5v-11Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"></path>
          <g filter="url(#55d6f982-cfb0-43d5-b1ce-33840dcf898f)">
            <path id="a04f8c46-600e-4f3d-a0d0-18aec2a64794" data-name="path-12" d="M908,1283h371v11c0,4.22-40,5-40,5H908s-40-.78-40-5v-11Z" transform="translate(0 -91)"></path>
          </g>
        </g>
        <path id="45b417de-e8a7-48cf-9a51-a395e9f84f91" data-name="gradient" d="M868,1283h40v16s-40-.78-40-5Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" opacity="0.07" fill="url(#0347f2e9-aa93-4a31-83dd-17fa4a18e4ef)" style="isolation: isolate"></path>
        <path id="c82d931c-b5dd-41df-8d28-8b31c0ddfc08" data-name="gradient" d="M1279,1283h-40v16s40-.78,40-5Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" opacity="0.07" fill="url(#48a5c464-8edd-45c4-9ce5-a29ab784ca76)" style="isolation: isolate"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="868adc6d-b9e8-4932-87a6-1078d21ee680" data-name="~SCREEN-HERE~">
        <g id="c080d29c-08b9-42d3-99f9-b333604f0ed7" data-name="Rectangle">
          <rect id="61fb43be-48cd-4ec6-b11b-6f8c5a6f0202" data-name="path-15" x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="1010" fill="#d8d8d8"></rect>
        </g>
        <g mask="url(#e5f414aa-2dc3-4e7e-beb9-c2665256ed3c)">
          <g>
            <image width="1618" height="1010" transform="translate(264 79)" xlink:href="http://res.cloudinary.com/bastienrobert/image/upload/v1519135713/cover_copie_vcpfee.jpg" style="isolation: isolate; height: auto;"></image>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

On chrome:
[image]

On firefox/safari:
[image]

Comment: correct, auto is only implemented in Chrome so far. You've already discovered that, what else could we tell you as an answer?

Comment: Perhaps any other alternative ? Using prefix, other CSS properties or JS ?

Comment: Figure out the actual size of the image and use those values.

Comment: So it will be javascript because the svg is generated using Middleman partials for different images sizes, pretty sad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**height: auto is an invalid value in SVG**

SVG is not html. `auto` isn't a valid value according to [the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#DataTypeLength).

> When a *length* is used in an SVG presentation attribute, the syntax
>   must match the following pattern:
>
> length ::= number ("em" | "ex" | "px" | "in" | "cm" | "mm" | "pt" |
>   "pc" | "%")?

**But...You can do what you want.**

The good news is that you can still do what you want. To achieve this we can use the `preserveAspectRatio`-attribute. Here is the [documentation on  preserveAspectRatio](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute).

The documentation describes the `preserveAspectRatio` on images:

> For ‘image’ elements, ‘preserveAspectRatio’ indicates how referenced
>   images should be fitted with respect to the reference rectangle and
>   whether the aspect ratio of the referenced image should be preserved
>   with respect to the current user coordinate system.

According to the documentation the syntax looks like this:

> **preserveAspectRatio="[defer] *align* []**

- Usually you can ignore defer.
- The align part indicates where the image is placed. We want to place it on the top-middle of the `viewBox`. Therefore this value will become `xMidYMin` indicating the image will be placed in the middle top.
- Setting `meetOrSlice` to `slice` will set the minimal width and minimal height of the image to that of the `viewBox`. Setting `meetOrSlice` to `meet` will set the maximal width and maximal height of the image to that of the `viewBox`. We want to see the top of your image in full width. Therefore we set `meetOrSlice` to `slice`.

With this information we can set up the `preserveAspectRatio`-attribute of the image. Note that the `viewBox` attribute is included since that is required by the spec.

```
<image 
   x="264" 
   y="79" 
   width="1618" 
   height="1010" 
   viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
   preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" 
   xlink:href="image.jpg">
</image>
```

**Here is your new code (I only changed the `<image>`):**

```html
<svg id="adf1338b-c638-44c9-9dd0-93df7f9f46b1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2148 1237.39">
  <defs>
    <filter id="e71a6e13-91a7-4c48-8db4-fd9f3d7680f9" x="-13.7" y="-110.5" width="128.3" height="140.2" name="filter-2">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetOuter1" dx="7.8" dy="7.8" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feGaussianBlur result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="81.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.06 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="952164c2-8d50-4072-8fbc-1daf64a9f996" data-name="Dégradé sans nom" x1="752.65" y1="994.07" x2="753.65" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -12, -1616691.37, 13126.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.04"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.04"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="cb01145d-084b-4051-a7b8-afc1075b337d" y="-94.6" width="100" height="107.1" name="filter-5">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetInner1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feComposite result="shadowInnerInner1" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha"></feComposite>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.02 0" in="shadowInnerInner1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 2" x1="744.83" y1="994.07" x2="743.59" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(80, 0, 0, -12, -57419, 13126.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
      id="d6b5fdf2-09db-48a0-a136-a0968d72d8fd"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 3"
      x1="743.59"
      y1="994.07"
      x2="744.59"
      y2="994.07"
      gradientTransform="matrix(80, 0, 0, -12, -59486.95, 13126.84)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 4" x1="752.65" y1="968.72" x2="753.65" y2="968.72" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#eaeaea" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="1b131c43-0dea-4a3e-b634-4bb33e458dcc" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 6" x1="753.15" y1="969.22" x2="753.15" y2="968.22" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="dc83dd5d-fe7a-4f3c-96dc-f9b3dd530f96" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 7" x1="753.15" y1="969.22" x2="753.15" y2="968.22" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.05"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.05"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="55d6f982-cfb0-43d5-b1ce-33840dcf898f" x="-0.1" y="-93.6" width="100.2" height="105.3" name="filter-13">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetInner1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feComposite result="shadowInnerInner1" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha"></feComposite>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.03 0" in="shadowInnerInner1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient
      id="0347f2e9-aa93-4a31-83dd-17fa4a18e4ef"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 8"
      x1="734.18"
      y1="984.18"
      x2="735.18"
      y2="984.18"
      gradientTransform="matrix(40, 0, 0, -16, -28499.14, 17037.76)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
      id="48a5c464-8edd-45c4-9ce5-a29ab784ca76"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 9"
      x1="735.17"
      y1="984.18"
      x2="734.17"
      y2="984.18"
      gradientTransform="matrix(40, 0, 0, -16, -28127.82, 17037.76)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <mask id="e5f414aa-2dc3-4e7e-beb9-c2665256ed3c" x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="1010" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <g transform="translate(0 -91)">
        <g id="5c9c027a-7ae5-4592-a798-6d4ba66f4659" data-name="mask-16">
          <rect id="b88cc6a8-61b0-4014-b1dc-ffc15d65cac1" data-name="path-15" x="264" y="170" width="1618" height="1010" fill="#fff"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g id="77173500-bfe4-412c-9f4c-6d18bf82908b" data-name="Artboard">
    <g id="98dd64aa-035e-4372-81a9-808b5df3da43" data-name="macbook">
      <g id="2528bcce-59cd-406f-8223-417b9dc2b419" data-name="bg">
        <g filter="url(#e71a6e13-91a7-4c48-8db4-fd9f3d7680f9)">
          <path
            id="a7e121fd-8fcd-4e60-8f74-4eb6bbc3617a"
            data-name="path-1"
            d="M296.42,91H1850.58c34,0,43.53,0,58.17,4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33,37.33c4.92,14.64,4.92,24.17,4.92,58.17V1223.58c0,34,0,43.53-4.92,58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33,37.33c-14.64,4.92-24.17,4.92-58.17,4.92H296.42c-34,0-43.53,0-58.17-4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33-37.33c-4.92-14.64-4.92-24.17-4.92-58.17V191.42c0-34,0-43.53,4.92-58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33-37.33C252.89,91,262.43,91,296.42,91Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"></path>
        </g>
        <path
          id="400dfe13-b733-4999-ba8f-7c75bc5675e2"
          data-name="path-1"
          d="M296.42,91H1850.58c34,0,43.53,0,58.17,4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33,37.33c4.92,14.64,4.92,24.17,4.92,58.17V1223.58c0,34,0,43.53-4.92,58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33,37.33c-14.64,4.92-24.17,4.92-58.17,4.92H296.42c-34,0-43.53,0-58.17-4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33-37.33c-4.92-14.64-4.92-24.17-4.92-58.17V191.42c0-34,0-43.53,4.92-58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33-37.33C252.89,91,262.43,91,296.42,91Z"
          transform="translate(0 -91)"
          fill="#fff"></path>
      </g>
      <path id="43c6a4ac-5af9-45b1-9c0a-e2b805fceea4" data-name="cam" d="M1070.5,133a6.5,6.5,0,1,1-6.5,6.5A6.5,6.5,0,0,1,1070.5,133Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#f2f2f2"></path>
      <g id="41b53099-7741-4f93-a5b1-bbc7d688aeca" data-name="Bottom">
        <g id="ed61ea5b-396c-4755-acc5-837900bb45dd" data-name="Rectangle-1">
          <polygon id="3f88510c-3940-406a-944f-ea423fac19a9" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192" fill="#fff"></polygon>
          <polygon id="12bddb6b-cf6b-4005-b437-57bd064462a3" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192" fill="url(#952164c2-8d50-4072-8fbc-1daf64a9f996)"></polygon>
          <g filter="url(#cb01145d-084b-4051-a7b8-afc1075b337d)">
            <polygon id="04c57957-d6c4-492a-af0d-9db3629d7056" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192"></polygon>
          </g>
        </g>
        <polygon id="9b3aec7b-87aa-41a2-8c6e-1a1021f35e95" data-name="gradient" points="2068 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 2068 1204 2068 1192" opacity="0.1" fill="url(#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c)" style="isolation: isolate"></polygon>
        <polygon id="2b964d54-6675-4afb-a411-aa203a5eaca1" data-name="gradient" points="0 1192 80 1192 80 1204 0 1204 0 1192" opacity="0.1" fill="url(#d6b5fdf2-09db-48a0-a136-a0968d72d8fd)" style="isolation: isolate"></polygon>
        <g id="0f4064a7-9754-48ad-8901-2956fe4271fa" data-name="bottom">
          <path id="6dfeff10-a16b-4114-9289-11ca4696184e" data-name="path-11" d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"></path>
          <path
            id="6ac336ae-89f9-44e0-8892-088e108b9b0c"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681)"></path>
          <path
            id="929a00e3-5dc1-434b-9ea2-499bfffeb4b7"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681)"></path>
          <path
            id="41d1f204-371f-4006-b6e3-3ca8e55170a4"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#1b131c43-0dea-4a3e-b634-4bb33e458dcc)"></path>
          <path
            id="3661128a-dd7f-4831-ad61-767d60316664"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#dc83dd5d-fe7a-4f3c-96dc-f9b3dd530f96)"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="be6e6ca0-ae80-4cfd-951c-f15752bfa1f4" data-name="Combined-shape-29">
          <path id="0381728f-4162-474f-a8a6-a34825b87739" data-name="path-12" d="M908,1283h371v11c0,4.22-40,5-40,5H908s-40-.78-40-5v-11Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"></path>
          <g filter="url(#55d6f982-cfb0-43d5-b1ce-33840dcf898f)">
            <path id="a04f8c46-600e-4f3d-a0d0-18aec2a64794" data-name="path-12" d="M908,1283h371v11c0,4.22-40,5-40,5H908s-40-.78-40-5v-11Z" transform="translate(0 -91)"></path>
          </g>
        </g>
        <path id="45b417de-e8a7-48cf-9a51-a395e9f84f91" data-name="gradient" d="M868,1283h40v16s-40-.78-40-5Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" opacity="0.07" fill="url(#0347f2e9-aa93-4a31-83dd-17fa4a18e4ef)" style="isolation: isolate"></path>
        <path id="c82d931c-b5dd-41df-8d28-8b31c0ddfc08" data-name="gradient" d="M1279,1283h-40v16s40-.78,40-5Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" opacity="0.07" fill="url(#48a5c464-8edd-45c4-9ce5-a29ab784ca76)" style="isolation: isolate"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="868adc6d-b9e8-4932-87a6-1078d21ee680" data-name="~SCREEN-HERE~">
        <g id="c080d29c-08b9-42d3-99f9-b333604f0ed7" data-name="Rectangle">
          <rect id="61fb43be-48cd-4ec6-b11b-6f8c5a6f0202" data-name="path-15" x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="1010" fill="#d8d8d8"></rect>
        </g>
        <g mask="url(#e5f414aa-2dc3-4e7e-beb9-c2665256ed3c)">
          <g>
            <image x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="1010" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" xlink:href="http://res.cloudinary.com/bastienrobert/image/upload/v1519135713/cover_copie_vcpfee.jpg"></image>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: auto [is a valid value for width/height in SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/geometry.html#Sizing). Only Chrome has implemented that part of the SVG 2 spec though. defer is gone in SVG 2, Firefox removed support a while ago. Not sure Chrome ever supported defer.

Comment: @Robert Longson As far as I am aware SVG 2.0 is currently still a draft / candidate recommendation ; https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/Overview.html#status. We probably shouldn't be using SVG 2.0 until it is endorsed by w3c.

Comment: Firefox, Chrome and Edge are all busily implementing it. The w3c needs 2 implementations of each feature before they sign off the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in any browser other than Google Chrome, as you found out. You will have to use have to find out the actual size of the image and put that in. Another option is to use JavaScript. Sorry.

So for you, your own code snippet would work.

```html
<svg id="adf1338b-c638-44c9-9dd0-93df7f9f46b1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2148 1237.39">
  <defs>
    <filter id="e71a6e13-91a7-4c48-8db4-fd9f3d7680f9" x="-13.7" y="-110.5" width="128.3" height="140.2" name="filter-2">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetOuter1" dx="7.8" dy="7.8" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feGaussianBlur result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="81.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.06 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="952164c2-8d50-4072-8fbc-1daf64a9f996" data-name="Dégradé sans nom" x1="752.65" y1="994.07" x2="753.65" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -12, -1616691.37, 13126.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.04"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.04"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="cb01145d-084b-4051-a7b8-afc1075b337d" y="-94.6" width="100" height="107.1" name="filter-5">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetInner1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feComposite result="shadowInnerInner1" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha"></feComposite>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.02 0" in="shadowInnerInner1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 2" x1="744.83" y1="994.07" x2="743.59" y2="994.07" gradientTransform="matrix(80, 0, 0, -12, -57419, 13126.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
      id="d6b5fdf2-09db-48a0-a136-a0968d72d8fd"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 3"
      x1="743.59"
      y1="994.07"
      x2="744.59"
      y2="994.07"
      gradientTransform="matrix(80, 0, 0, -12, -59486.95, 13126.84)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 4" x1="752.65" y1="968.72" x2="753.65" y2="968.72" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#eaeaea" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="1b131c43-0dea-4a3e-b634-4bb33e458dcc" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 6" x1="753.15" y1="969.22" x2="753.15" y2="968.22" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.07"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="dc83dd5d-fe7a-4f3c-96dc-f9b3dd530f96" data-name="Dégradé sans nom 7" x1="753.15" y1="969.22" x2="753.15" y2="968.22" gradientTransform="matrix(2148, 0, 0, -33.39, -1616692.1, 33656.27)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.05"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.05"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="55d6f982-cfb0-43d5-b1ce-33840dcf898f" x="-0.1" y="-93.6" width="100.2" height="105.3" name="filter-13">
      <feOffset result="shadowOffsetInner1" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha"></feOffset>
      <feComposite result="shadowInnerInner1" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" in="shadowOffsetInner1" in2="SourceAlpha"></feComposite>
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.03 0" in="shadowInnerInner1"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient
      id="0347f2e9-aa93-4a31-83dd-17fa4a18e4ef"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 8"
      x1="734.18"
      y1="984.18"
      x2="735.18"
      y2="984.18"
      gradientTransform="matrix(40, 0, 0, -16, -28499.14, 17037.76)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
      id="48a5c464-8edd-45c4-9ce5-a29ab784ca76"
      data-name="Dégradé sans nom 9"
      x1="735.17"
      y1="984.18"
      x2="734.17"
      y2="984.18"
      gradientTransform="matrix(40, 0, 0, -16, -28127.82, 17037.76)"
      xlink:href="#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c"></linearGradient>
    <mask id="e5f414aa-2dc3-4e7e-beb9-c2665256ed3c" x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="1010" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <g transform="translate(0 -91)">
        <g id="5c9c027a-7ae5-4592-a798-6d4ba66f4659" data-name="mask-16">
          <rect id="b88cc6a8-61b0-4014-b1dc-ffc15d65cac1" data-name="path-15" x="264" y="170" width="1618" height="1010" fill="#fff"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g id="77173500-bfe4-412c-9f4c-6d18bf82908b" data-name="Artboard">
    <g id="98dd64aa-035e-4372-81a9-808b5df3da43" data-name="macbook">
      <g id="2528bcce-59cd-406f-8223-417b9dc2b419" data-name="bg">
        <g filter="url(#e71a6e13-91a7-4c48-8db4-fd9f3d7680f9)">
          <path
            id="a7e121fd-8fcd-4e60-8f74-4eb6bbc3617a"
            data-name="path-1"
            d="M296.42,91H1850.58c34,0,43.53,0,58.17,4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33,37.33c4.92,14.64,4.92,24.17,4.92,58.17V1223.58c0,34,0,43.53-4.92,58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33,37.33c-14.64,4.92-24.17,4.92-58.17,4.92H296.42c-34,0-43.53,0-58.17-4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33-37.33c-4.92-14.64-4.92-24.17-4.92-58.17V191.42c0-34,0-43.53,4.92-58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33-37.33C252.89,91,262.43,91,296.42,91Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"></path>
        </g>
        <path
          id="400dfe13-b733-4999-ba8f-7c75bc5675e2"
          data-name="path-1"
          d="M296.42,91H1850.58c34,0,43.53,0,58.17,4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33,37.33c4.92,14.64,4.92,24.17,4.92,58.17V1223.58c0,34,0,43.53-4.92,58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33,37.33c-14.64,4.92-24.17,4.92-58.17,4.92H296.42c-34,0-43.53,0-58.17-4.92a62.76,62.76,0,0,1-37.33-37.33c-4.92-14.64-4.92-24.17-4.92-58.17V191.42c0-34,0-43.53,4.92-58.17a62.76,62.76,0,0,1,37.33-37.33C252.89,91,262.43,91,296.42,91Z"
          transform="translate(0 -91)"
          fill="#fff"></path>
      </g>
      <path id="43c6a4ac-5af9-45b1-9c0a-e2b805fceea4" data-name="cam" d="M1070.5,133a6.5,6.5,0,1,1-6.5,6.5A6.5,6.5,0,0,1,1070.5,133Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#f2f2f2"></path>
      <g id="41b53099-7741-4f93-a5b1-bbc7d688aeca" data-name="Bottom">
        <g id="ed61ea5b-396c-4755-acc5-837900bb45dd" data-name="Rectangle-1">
          <polygon id="3f88510c-3940-406a-944f-ea423fac19a9" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192" fill="#fff"></polygon>
          <polygon id="12bddb6b-cf6b-4005-b437-57bd064462a3" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192" fill="url(#952164c2-8d50-4072-8fbc-1daf64a9f996)"></polygon>
          <g filter="url(#cb01145d-084b-4051-a7b8-afc1075b337d)">
            <polygon id="04c57957-d6c4-492a-af0d-9db3629d7056" data-name="path-4" points="0 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 0 1204 0 1192"></polygon>
          </g>
        </g>
        <polygon id="9b3aec7b-87aa-41a2-8c6e-1a1021f35e95" data-name="gradient" points="2068 1192 2148 1192 2148 1204 2068 1204 2068 1192" opacity="0.1" fill="url(#45e2d6df-7e0f-4299-baf8-38080dc72e3c)" style="isolation: isolate"></polygon>
        <polygon id="2b964d54-6675-4afb-a411-aa203a5eaca1" data-name="gradient" points="0 1192 80 1192 80 1204 0 1204 0 1192" opacity="0.1" fill="url(#d6b5fdf2-09db-48a0-a136-a0968d72d8fd)" style="isolation: isolate"></polygon>
        <g id="0f4064a7-9754-48ad-8901-2956fe4271fa" data-name="bottom">
          <path id="6dfeff10-a16b-4114-9289-11ca4696184e" data-name="path-11" d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"></path>
          <path
            id="6ac336ae-89f9-44e0-8892-088e108b9b0c"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681)"></path>
          <path
            id="929a00e3-5dc1-434b-9ea2-499bfffeb4b7"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#ff74df12-f810-4f37-96f0-568d0d222681)"></path>
          <path
            id="41d1f204-371f-4006-b6e3-3ca8e55170a4"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#1b131c43-0dea-4a3e-b634-4bb33e458dcc)"></path>
          <path
            id="3661128a-dd7f-4831-ad61-767d60316664"
            data-name="path-11"
            d="M0,1295H2148c-12.69,7.93-125.29,40.45-500,32-33.09,0-965.67-1-1170-1-237.14,0-335.31,1-424.91-16.31C21.72,1303.64,6,1298.65,0,1295Z"
            transform="translate(0 -91)"
            fill="url(#dc83dd5d-fe7a-4f3c-96dc-f9b3dd530f96)"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="be6e6ca0-ae80-4cfd-951c-f15752bfa1f4" data-name="Combined-shape-29">
          <path id="0381728f-4162-474f-a8a6-a34825b87739" data-name="path-12" d="M908,1283h371v11c0,4.22-40,5-40,5H908s-40-.78-40-5v-11Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" fill="#fff"></path>
          <g filter="url(#55d6f982-cfb0-43d5-b1ce-33840dcf898f)">
            <path id="a04f8c46-600e-4f3d-a0d0-18aec2a64794" data-name="path-12" d="M908,1283h371v11c0,4.22-40,5-40,5H908s-40-.78-40-5v-11Z" transform="translate(0 -91)"></path>
          </g>
        </g>
        <path id="45b417de-e8a7-48cf-9a51-a395e9f84f91" data-name="gradient" d="M868,1283h40v16s-40-.78-40-5Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" opacity="0.07" fill="url(#0347f2e9-aa93-4a31-83dd-17fa4a18e4ef)" style="isolation: isolate"></path>
        <path id="c82d931c-b5dd-41df-8d28-8b31c0ddfc08" data-name="gradient" d="M1279,1283h-40v16s40-.78,40-5Z" transform="translate(0 -91)" opacity="0.07" fill="url(#48a5c464-8edd-45c4-9ce5-a29ab784ca76)" style="isolation: isolate"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="868adc6d-b9e8-4932-87a6-1078d21ee680" data-name="~SCREEN-HERE~">
        <g id="c080d29c-08b9-42d3-99f9-b333604f0ed7" data-name="Rectangle">
          <rect id="61fb43be-48cd-4ec6-b11b-6f8c5a6f0202" data-name="path-15" x="264" y="79" width="1618" height="1010" fill="#d8d8d8"></rect>
        </g>
        <g mask="url(#e5f414aa-2dc3-4e7e-beb9-c2665256ed3c)">
          <g>
            <image width="1618" height="1010" transform="translate(264 79)" xlink:href="http://res.cloudinary.com/bastienrobert/image/upload/v1519135713/cover_copie_vcpfee.jpg" style="isolation: isolate; height: auto;"></image>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```